# Test custom jQuery plugins locally in Angular app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, jquery-plugins

I have created a simple plugin using `JavaScript` and `jQuery`. I havent published it yet but I want to test it in my `Angular5` application locally. The plugin is in a folder `C://myPlugin`. How can I invoke it in my application?
Do I just add it to the script tag in the body of `index.html`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import plugin from 'plugin';

...
ngOnInit() {
    // if it has jQuery prototyping
    $(el).plugin(options);
    // with Javascript
    const plugin = new plugin();
}
```

**Note:** Make sure your is correctly exported.

**Update:**
Move the folder of your plugin into the root of angular app.
the structure will be like this. (When using angular cli)

```
src
 |-- app
   |-- plugin
      |-- plugin.js
   |-- app.component.ts
```

Then import it into your app.component.ts for instance:

```
import plugin from './plugin/plugin';
```

Comment: When you say `import plugin from 'plugin'` , where do i import it from? It has not been published in npm. At this point, it is just in a folder in my C:

Comment: I added the plugin folder under app. And in my `app.component.ts` when I try to `import jquery.myPlugin from './myPlugin/js'`, I get an error - `Cannot find module 'myPlugin/js'`

Comment: You need to export your module using `exports.yourModule` or using es2015 `import` syntax